# VIM FTP Auto-Upload Upon Save?

Tags: macos, vim, ftp, sftp, macvim

Is there a plug-in or something already in mac VIM to get this done? It's the one feature that Sublime has that I really wish VIM had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to find a suitable plugin at [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=ftp&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search). Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17474775/498656) for a possible lead.

Anyway, my opinion is that such a feature belongs to your FTP client and not to your *text editor*.

And you are lucky, some of the most venerable Mac OS X FTP clients have some kind of "autosync" feature:

- [Interarchy](http://nolobe.com/interarchy/) (Auto Uploads)
- [Yummy FTP](http://www.yummysoftware.com/) (FTP Watcher)

[Macfusion](http://macfusionapp.org/), [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/) Disks and Interarchy's "Net Disks" are an alternative that lets you mount an FTP server like a local disk.

All philosophy issues aside, did you know that you can browse FTP servers directly from Vim without adding anything? See `:h netrw`.

Comment: This is a bad answer in my opinion for a feature that needs to be added to VIM.  Working on a remote directory has its disadvantages and leaving a separate FTP program running in the background is a waste of resources.  Most text editors such as Sublime Text have a great SFTP plugin that auto saves files to the server when you save meanwhile you can still find functions and other text in your entire project.  Not just your current file.  netrw is fine for a one shot upload/download, but again doesn't work well in my situations.  Version control isn't good for this either.

Comment: @Goddard, I think you misunderstand what constitutes a bad answer, here. You think it should while I think it doesn't matter, but the truth is that the asked feature doesn't exist in Vim at the moment. Since Vim can't do natively what is asked, my answer does two things: 1. point the asker toward vim.org where he may or may not find a plugin that does what he wants and 2. propose alternatives solutions. You may not like those alternatives or they may not do exactly what is asked but they are the askers *only* solutions *at the moment*.

Comment: @Goddard, if you know of a better way to do what the asker wants, feel free to add an answer. Downvoting a constructive answer just because it pisses you off by showing a limitation of our favorite editor is useless.

Comment: I just decided to set up git so that when I do a git push it goes to the server. I feel like that accomplishes what I need. I did actually look on VIM's website romaini. That's why I finally got frustrated enough to ask the question here. I was hoping for a better answer rather than being scolded for not having first looked on vim's website  and other places before asking here when I did look at vim's website first.

Comment: You should have said so in your question. There's no way to know that from the information you gave. Also yes, Git or some other VCS is vastly better anyway.

Answer (score 1):

you maybe looking for vim-sftp-sync plugin:

https://github.com/eshion/vim-sftp-sync

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a plugin for this purpose. It can be found here: https://github.com/hesselbom/vim-hsftp

It allows you to download or upload the current file through sftp.

It's in early stages but it has worked for my purposes and you're free to fork it or contribute if you'd like!